# Is it possible for a python script to check whether row exists in google sheets before writing that row?

Tags: python, google-sheets, beautifulsoup

I have a python script that searches for vehicles on a vehicle listing site and writes the results to a spreadsheet. What I want is to automate this script to run every night to get new listings, but what I don't want is to create numerous duplicates if the listing exists each day that the script is run.

So is it possible to get the script to check whether that row (potential duplicate) already exists before writing a new row?

To clarify the code I have works perfectly to print the results exactly how I want them into the google sheets document, what I am trying to do is to run a check before it prints new lines into the sheet to see if that result already exists. Is that clearer? With thanks in advance.

Here is a screenshot of an example where I might have a row already existing with the specific title, but one of the column cells may have a different value in it and I only want to update the original row with the latest/highest price value.

[image]

UPDATE:

I am trying something like this but it just seems to print everything rather than only if it doesn't already exist which is what I am trying to do.

```
listing = [title, img['src'], video, vin,loc, exterior_colour, interior_colour, 'N/A', mileage, gearbox, 'N/A', 'Live', auction_date,'', '£' + bid.attrs['amount'][:-3], 'The Market', '', '', '', '', year, make, model, variant]

    list_of_dicts = sheet2.get_all_records()

    # Convert listing into dictionary output to be read by following statement to see if listing exists in sheet before printing
    i = iter(listing)
    d_listing = dict(zip(i, i))


    if not d_listing in list_of_dicts:
        print(listing)
    #print(title, img['src'], video, vin,loc, exterior_colour, interior_colour, 'N/A', mileage, gearbox, 'N/A', 'Live', auction_date,'', '£' + bid.attrs['amount'][:-3], 'The Market', '', '', '', '', year, make, model, variant)
        index = 2
        row = [title, img['src'], video, vin,loc, exterior_colour, interior_colour, 'N/A', mileage, gearbox, 'N/A', 'Live', auction_date,'', '£' + bid.attrs['amount'][:-3], 'The Market', '', '', '', '', year, make, model, variant]
        sheet2.insert_row(row,index)
```

My code is:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("CAR AGGREGATOR")

sheet2 = sheet.worksheet("Auctions - Live")



url = "https://themarket.co.uk/live.xml"
get_url = requests.get(url)
get_text = get_url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for loc in soup.select('url > loc'):
    loc = loc.text
    r=requests.get(loc)
    c=r.content
    hoop = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'lxml')

    current_bid = soup.find('div', 'bid-step__header')
    bid = soup.find('bid-display')
    title = soup.find('h2').text.split()
    year = title[0]
    if not year:
        year = ''

    if any(make in 'ASTON ALFA HEALEY ROVER Arnolt Bristol Amilcar  Amphicar LOREAN De Cadenet Cosworth'.split() for make in title):
        make = title[1] + ' ' + title[2]
        model = title[3]
        try:
            variant = title[4]
        except:
            variant = ''
    else:
        make = title[1]
        model = title[2]
        try:
            variant = title[3]
            if 'REIMAGINED' in variant:
                variant = 'REIMAGINED BY SINGER'
            if 'SINGER' in variant:
                variant = 'REIMAGINED BY SINGER'
        except:
            variant = ''
    title = year + ' ' + make + ' ' + model
    img = soup.find('img')

    vehicle_details = soup.find('ul', 'vehicle__overview')
    try:
        mileage = vehicle_details.find_all('li')[1].text.split()[2]
    except:
        mileage = ''
    try:
        vin = vehicle_details.find_all('li')[2].text.split()[2]
    except:
        vin = ''
    try:
        gearbox = vehicle_details.find_all('li')[4].text.split()[2]
    except:
        gearbox = 'N/A'
    try:
        exterior_colour = vehicle_details.find_all('li')[5].text.split()[1:]
        exterior_colour = "-".join(exterior_colour)

    except:
        exterior_colour = 'N/A'
    try:
        interior_colour = vehicle_details.find_all('li')[6].text.split()[1:]
        interior_colour = "-".join(interior_colour)
    except:
        interior_colour = 'N/A'

    try:
        video = soup.find('iframe')['src']
    except:
        video = ''


    tag = soup.countdown
    try:
        auction_date = tag.attrs['formatted_date'].split()
        auction_day = auction_date[0][:2]
        auction_month = auction_date[1]
        auction_year = auction_date[2]
        auction_time = auction_date[3]
        auction_date = auction_day + ' ' + auction_month + ' ' + auction_year + ' ' + auction_time
    except:
        continue

    print(title, img['src'], video, vin,loc, exterior_colour, interior_colour, 'N/A', mileage, gearbox, 'N/A', 'Live', auction_date,'', '£' + bid.attrs['amount'][:-3], 'The Market', '', '', '', '', year, make, model, variant)
    index = 2
    row = [title, img['src'], video, vin,loc, exterior_colour, interior_colour, 'N/A', mileage, gearbox, 'N/A', 'Live', auction_date,'', '£' + bid.attrs['amount'][:-3], 'The Market', '', '', '', '', year, make, model, variant]
    sheet2.insert_row(row,index)
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you not able to retrieve the data from the GoogleSheet, or do you not know how to check for duplicate entries in the data? Please reduce your question to a minimal example. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited my question @jonathan.scholbach, I guess the thing I don't know how to do is to check whether there are duplicate entries before it prints/writes another if that makes sense? The problem also is that it the data may exist in the sheet but with a different value in one of the columns, I want to update just the column with new data.

Answer (score 0):

I would load all data in two dictionaries, one representing the freshly scraped information, the other one the full information of the GoogleSheet. (To load the information from GoogleSheet, use its API, as described [in Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).)

Both dictionaries, let's call them `scraped` and `sheets`, could have the titles as keys, and all the other columns as value (represented in a dictionary), so they would look like this:

```
{
    "1928 Aston Martin V8": {
        "Link": "...",
        "Price": "12 $",
    },
    ...
}
```

Then update the Sheets-dictionary with [`dict.update()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update):

```
sheets.update(scraped)
```

and rewrite the Google Sheet with the data in `sheets`.

Without exactly knowing your update logic, I cannot give a more specific advice than this.

Comment: Thanks @jonathan.scholbach, I have updated my question as I think I understand what you are suggesting, is that what you meant? I can't quite get it working but am hoping you can help? I am able to get the results from the spreadsheet using .get_all_records() but need to make sure I know how to update the records properly based on finding the existing record (dictionary entry)